# Newton's Method Solving an Equation

Tags: numerical-methods

What would be the Newton's method in the form $x_{k+1}=g(x_k)$ to solve the equation $$f(x)=x^2-2bx+b^2-d^2=0$$ in which both $b>0,d>0$ are parameters? Additionally, I need to show that $|g'(x)|\le 1/2$ whenever $|x-b|\ge d/\sqrt{2}$ and also that $|g(x)-b|\ge d/\sqrt{2}$ whenever $|x-b|\ge d/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: If you already have the equation in that form, what do you need Newton's method for? The quadratic formula immediately gives the exact roots $b\pm d$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm So, does that mean that there isn't a way to put it into the form $x_{k+1}=g(x_k)$?

Comment: There is. Convergence is another problem.

Comment: in this example you don't need the Newton method

Comment: @user310546: Why would you _want_ to do that? If you already have $b$ and $d$, simply adding and subtracting those known numbers will give you the _exact_ roots _immediately_, with less effort than any conceivable stepwise approximation method would need.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I understand. But I need it to show the rest of my question.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I know that $$g(x)=x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}$$ and we can use that to find $g$. But I can't figure out the second question still.